# continuity at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't find on complex analysys texts the precise definition of continuity at $\infty$. In particular, my lecturer said: all entire non costant functions aren't continous at infinity, since they are unbounded (by Liouville). I thought the following: take the complex plane with the point $\infty$, i.e. the Riemann sphere. This is a compact set. If f is entire non constant and I suppose $f$ to be continous also at $\infty$, then $f$ should be continous on $\mathbb C \cup\infty$, then bounded (by Weierstrass). Absurd. Is it right?

Comment: A quick definition for continuity at infinity is: define $g(z)=f(1/z)$. Is there a definition of $g(0)$ that makes $g$ continuous?  Analytic at infinity would mean the same. You'll need conditions on the domain of $f$ for this definition to work, possibly different based on whether you are talking analytic or just continuous

Comment: Maybe you didn't express yourself too well, but I understand your idea and I think that it is completely correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuity at $\infty$ is usually understood to be continuity at the opposite of $0$ in Riemann sphere, that is correct (in general, study of meromorphic functions etc. makes sense in that context, in some ways more so than in the complex plane alone).

I don't understand what you mean by "absurd" -- you've simply shown that a complex-valued function holomorphic on $\bf C$ and continuous at $\infty$ is constant, and that is correct.

This may not be true if you allow the values to be $\infty$, too. Identity on the entire Riemann sphere is certainly holomorphic everywhere and nonconstant.

Comment: yes, i forgot to assume $f$ non constant, i've edited

Comment: what does it mean "opposite of zero" in Riemann sphere?

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni: That means $\infty$ in the Riemann sphere. It is opposite of zero if you look at it geometrically. :) Or algebraically, $\infty=1/0$.

Comment: So, to be explicit: $f$ is continuous at $\infty$ iff one of two things happens: 1) Either $\lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)$ exists and is a complex number $t$. (This is as saying that $\lim_{zeta\to 0}g(\zeta)=t$, where $g(\zeta)=f(1/z)$, so $g$ can be extended to a continuous function at $0$.) 2) Or $\lim_{z\to\infty} |f(z)|=+\infty$. (This is as saying that $\lim_{\zeta\to 0} h(\zeta)=0$, where $h(\zeta)=1/f(1/z)$.)

Comment: In particular, in order for $f$ to be continuous at $\infty$, we need that $f(z)$ be defined for all complex $z$ in a neighborhood of infinity, that is, there is an $R$ such that $f(z)$ is defined for all $z$ with $|z|\ge R$. (One can tweak this definition, to include other situations where this neighborhood condition fails. But this is the standard meaning.)

Comment: But if you allow the identity function to be continuous at infinity, you must also allow any function with a pole to be continuous at the pole.

Comment: Yeah, if continuity at infinity allows the value $\infty$, then the theorem is not true, since any polynomial would be continuous at $\infty$

Comment: (Hmmm... I just saw all the typos in my first comment. Sorry about that.)